# What's the name of this succulent?

Tags: identification, succulents

I recently bought this plant, but the seller didn't know what's the species. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the Internet for a while, I discovered it's called [Aichryson Laxum](https://www.google.com/search?q=Aichryson%20Laxum&oq=Aichryson%20Laxum&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61j0l2.369j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). The common names seems to be "Tree of Love".

Comment: I just zoomed in on the picture and i realized that the leaves have this fuzzy texture to them. Not matching the characteristics of a jade plant leaf. So yes, i believe you've got the plant's name right afterall

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you have there is called a jade plant. The shape of the leaves makes it very obvious to tell. Though the lighting does throw you off at first. They're easy to take care of. Just dont over water it or place it in complete darkness.

Comment: It's actually neither a jade nor dwarf jade plant. It turned out to be Aichryson laxum :)